# Genus of the two-component unlink

Tags: general-topology

Question: Calculate the genus of the two-component unlink.

Here's my attempt:

Number of boundary component = $2$

- $V = 2$ (one for each component)
- $E = 2$ (one for each component)
- $F = 2$ (one for each component)

Therefore the Euler Characteristic $= 2-2+2 = 2-2g-2$

This yields $g = -1$

Here, I am not sure if my working is correct because I got a negative value for $g$. Is this possible? Have I made a mistake in taking into account the number of boundary components?

Answer (score 1):

Your method was right, (using the formulae $\chi=2-2g-b$ and $\chi=V-E+F$), however you made a mistake when counting simplices (and possibly when building the seifert surface - which remember should be connected).

The minimal-genus Seifert surface of a two component unlink is a cylinder which we can view as a square with two opposite edges identified with the same orientation.This square has $2$ vertices because the top pair and bottom pair are identified after gluing. The square has $3$ edges because one pair, of the four edges of the square are identified. And the square has $1$ face.

This gives $$\chi=V-E+F=2-3+1=0$$ and so $$0=\chi=2-2g-b=-2g\\ \Longrightarrow g=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error. May I also clarify why the Seifert surface of a two component unlink is a cylinder? I assumed there should not be any connection since the two discs are not linked to each other at all.

Comment: By definition of a Seifert surface, it has to be a compact, **connected**, orientable surface with the link as its boundary, embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.